# Error in SSMS while scheduling jobs

Tags: stored-procedures, scheduled-tasks, ssms, jobs, execute

I am trying to set up a job which populates data to a table after executing stored procedure.

```
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[sp_WarehouseAttendance_New]

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
```

But I keep getting this error as below.

```
The OLE DB Provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "sql10" reported an error. 
Execution terminated by the provider because a resource limit was reached. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 7399) Cannot fetch the rowset from OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "sql10"..
[SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 7421) OLE DB provider  "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "sql10" returned message "Query timeout expired".
[SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 7412). The step failed.
```

I have tried including `DBCC freeproccache` before stored proc but it doesnt help.

Please let me know how this can be avoided.

[image: Job_Error]

[image: Job_Error_cntd1]

[image: Job_Error_cntd3]

Comment: There could be a number of causes causing they query to run slow,  fragmented indexes, deadlock etc. This is not a fix, but to aid in diagnostics you could increase the execution time allowed for query execution to try and find out exactly how long the query takes to run and then see if the query finishes given extra time or just hangs...

Answer (score 0):

I followed these steps:

To set a time limit for remote queries

1.In Object Explorer, right-click a server and select Properties.

2.Click the Connections node.

3.Under Remote server connections, in the Remote query timeout box, type or select a value from 0 through 2,147,483,647 to set the maximum number seconds for SQL Server to wait before timing out.